# JS Copy command in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am using the following js code for copy the selection to clipboard.

```
document.execCommand('copy');
```

It works fine for chrome and firefox but in IE it prompts me to allow access to copy command then i able to copy. I want this prompt should not show just copy the text. Anyway to suppress this popup?

```
function clip(text) {
  var copyElement = document.createElement('input');
  copyElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  copyElement.setAttribute('value', text);
  copyElement = document.body.appendChild(copyElement);
  copyElement.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  copyElement.remove();
}
```

You can try this on IE
https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: Tools | Internet Options | Security | Internet Zone , Custom level ... In the Script section there's item Allow Programmatic clipboard access -> tick Enable.

Comment: Yes but i want it with the JS code.

Comment: Really?? You can't access Windows'/IE's internet options via JS.

Comment: You can send me the useful link where i can change the option vis JS

Comment: There's no such link. Think about a world where arbitrary web pages could access the registry of users machines ... Huh! It's a user's choise to allow or deny programmatic use of the clipboard, you can't do anything, only ask users to allow your page to use the clipboard.

Comment: Uninstall internet explorer... Murder everybody who uses it and complains about it

Comment: @Stender I can deny programmatic use of the clipboard in FF too, and also most likely Chrome has this option too. It will be a mass murder then ...

Comment: @Teemu I was only referring to the "people" still swearing to IE - so it is only about 15% of the people using the internet  - acceptable loss in my POV.

Comment: @Stender 15% of potential Internet users is about a billion people ...

Comment: @Teemu "Acceptable loss in my POV."  - second suggestion would be to have microsoft stop the support, development and forced install of IE - less people would die this way.

Comment: https://www.change.org/p/discontinue-internet-explorer

Comment: @Stender But ... but ... That's cruel, I love IE and all the nice things you can do with it locally. Safari is even worse than IE what comes to showing web pages, I'd prefer to shoot Safari down as well = ).

Answer (score -1):

```js
var copyElement = document.createElement('input');      
copyElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');   
copyElement.setAttribute('value',' ' );    
document.body.appendChild(copyElement);   
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.textContent = "copy";
document.body.appendChild(btn)
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyText = document.querySelector('input');
  copyText.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but try to run this on IE 11 then you will get prompt first to allow access to copy clipboard. This is what i don't want.